# url вКонтакте

Tags: вконтакте

Какими средствами обрабатывается url вКонтакте 
Меня интересует как работает сервер и страницы когда  url например 
http://vkontakte.ru/id**27063599**
(Я не знаю как правильно сформулировать вопрос)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//.htaccess

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)$ index.php?get=$1 [L]

где http://vkontakte.ru/username или http://vkontakte.ru/id123456789

на самом деле работает как http://vkontakte.ru/index.php?get=username или http://vkontakte.ru/index.php?get=123456789

Рвемвся в БД по запросу WHERE `user_unic` = '".$_GET['get']."'
```

Надеюсь принцип объяснил нормально)

Comment: А можно ссылку, где об этом подробнее сказано,  пожалуйста.

Answer (score -1):

**$_GET параметры.** через них скорее всего, ну а там получаешь и обрабатываешь их.

Comment: Там же нету этих GET знаков как ? = или &
Тут каким то другим образом
Если бы через ошибку 404 и тем файлом обрабатывалась, то  такого бы (http://vkontakte.ru/sdffdsfd) не было

Comment: А кто сказал что нельзя передавать GET параметры так

зачем афишировать как у тебя передаются параметры?
site.com/user/shrek

site.com/page/about

Это все настраивается через .htaccess
допустим так



RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php

Comment: можно вообще без htaccess =)

Расспарсить значение $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] и вперед =)